# SSIS package fails to run when called from a SQL Server Agent job step

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, script-task, sql-job

I have an SSRS report. I am downloading that as an Excel file through SSIS package. I have created a script task for that. This is working fine.

But the problem is when I am trying to run the SSIS package through SQL Server Agent job, it fails. I am not able to find where I am going wrong in this?

Please help me solve this.

I have already tried creating Desktop folder in

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile
```

I have also tried changing the ProtectionLevel to DontSaveSensitive at both project and package level.

> Error Description: The script returned a failure result.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

Comment: Run the All Executions report on the SSIS Package. You can do this from the Integration Services Catalog.

Comment: Does the account running the package (the “Run as” field on the job step) have the necessary permissions?

Comment: @userfl89 how to check if that user has necessary permissions? It shows SQL Server Agent Service Account.

Comment: @JWeezy can you help me by explaining more?

Comment: @sangita https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4812/reporting-with-the-sql-server-integration-services-catalog/

Comment: @SangitA first what is the specific error message you’re receiving? And you can give the SQL Server Agent account permissions for the folder containing the files right-clicking the folder > Properties > Security tab and adding the account. You can confirm the name of the SQL Server Agent account in SQL Server Configuration Manger.